# How to decode a text string encoded in the ISDB (ARIB) Transport streams?

Tags: unicode, character

How to decode a text string encoded in the ISDB (ARIB) Transport streams? Some encoding technique is specified in Chapter 7 of Part 2 (Mono media Coding) of  ARIB STD-B24 Version 5.2 (Volume 1) specification. But I am not sure whether this encoding is different from other standard Japanese character encoding techniques,  like EUC-JP, ISO-2022-JP, JIS X208 etc.What is this encoding standard name?

If I know the encoding name (code page) used in the ISDB streams, the I can use third party libraries like ICU as follows.

UConverter *ucnv_open (const char *converterName, UErrorCode *err)
conv = ucnv_open("shift_jis", &status);
len = ucnv_toUChars(conv, target, 100, source, strlen(source), &status);
ucnv_close(conv);

I also tried to decode an ARIB string taken from a ISDB Transport Stream on our own, but I am not through as I have encountered several issues, which are not clear to me.

There are 4 Graphics sets G0, G1, G2 and G3. What I have understood is that the initial values of the sets are
G0 : Kanji system set
G1 : Alphanumeric set
G2 : Hiragana set
G3 : Macro code set

Can the values of G0, G1, G2 and G3 be changed at times or they remain fixed?
What is this Macro code set?

At the time of decoding, there are two concepts, "Invocation of code elements" and "Designation of graphic sets". How to use this from the escape codes? For example I tried to decode the following string taken from a stream:

1b 7c c1 e3 f3 cd eb 26 41 1b 7d fe 4e 78 30 26 37 6b 3a 27 ce 4b 21 42 27 0e 28 1b 7c eb f9 eb 29 0f 21 21 0e 23 30 38 1b 24 3b 0f 7a 6a 7a 56 7a 59

How to get GL and GR values, say for the above string and whether to use 2 bytes or 1 byte per character? It will be extremely helpful if anybody can give some hint to decode the above string.

Answer (score 1):

Decoding made by

6-STD-B24v5_2-1p3-E1.pdf

Part 2, Chapter 7

Default sets Part 3, Chapter 8

Designation

```
G0 = Kanji (2 Byte) JIS X 0213:2004 8-bit code vs Unicode mapping table
G1 = AlphaNumeric (1 Byte)
G2 = Hiragana (1 Byte)
G3 = Macro code set (not decoded by the example below!!)
```

Invocation

```
GL <= G0
GR <= G2
```

Decoding:

```
1b 7c // Invocation GR <= G3
c1    // Right Table, Makro, Symbol..
e3    // ... sorry no ..
f3    // ... idea ..
cd    // ...
eb    // ...
26 41 // Left table, 2 bytes 0x2641 U+03B1  # GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA
1b 7d // Invocation GR <= G2
fe    // right table hiragana WideChar($7E + $3020);
4e 78 // Left table 0x4E78  U+604B  # <cjk>
30 26 //           0x3026   U+611B  # <cjk>
37 6b //           0x376B   U+7D50  # <cjk>
3a 27 //           0x3A27   U+5A5A  # <cjk> 
ce    // right table hiragana WideChar($4E + $3020);
4b 21 // left table 0x4B21  U+6CD5  # <cjk>
42 27 // 0x4227 U+5247  # <cjk>
0e    // Invocation GL <= G1
28    // left table "(" 
1b 7c // Invocation GR <= G3
eb    // right table, makro, symbols
f9    // ... no idea
eb    // ... no idea
29    // left table ")" 
0f    // Invocation GL <= G0
21 21 // left table 0x2121  U+3000  # IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
0e    // Invocation GL <= G1
23    // left table "#"
30    // left table "0"
38    // left table "8"
1b 24 3b // Designation G0 <= Additional Symbols
0f    // Invocation GL <= G0
7a 6a // Left Table, addional symbols 2 Byte code, cell 74 row 90 (rebroadcast)
7a 56 // cell 54 row 90 (closed-captioned broadcast)
7a 59 // cell 57 row 90 (stereo broadcasting service)
```

αゞ恋愛結婚の法則()　#08

Full α ゞ love marriage law () #08